# XML serialization for multiple Partial Public Classes

Tags: xml, vb.net, xml-serialization

I'm struggling when trying to serialize multiple partial public classes generated by using the xsd.exe tool.

I created new instances for each class to fill in the details but can't seem to serialize them together into one xml file.

```
    Dim id As New Identifier  'partial class 1
    id.Identifier_Type = "Material"
    id.Identifier_Value = "MAT/001"
    Dim id2 As New id2         'partial class 2
    id2.string = "stuff"
    id2.string2 = "more"
    id2.string3 = "Some Stuff"
    Dim id3 As New id3          'partial class 3
    id3.string ="type"

    Dim serializer As New XmlSerializer(id.GetType)

    Dim writer As TextWriter = New StreamWriter("c:\stack\text.xml")

    serializer.Serialize(writer, id)

    writer.Close()
```

All I seem to get is one partial class, how can I combine them together?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the [XML standard](https://www.w3.org/TR/REC-xml/#NT-document), a valid XML file must have one and only one [root element](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Root_element), for instance:

```
<Identifier>
    <Identifier_Type>Material</Identifier_Type>
    <Identifier_Value>MAT/001</Identifier_Value>
</Identifier>
```

It sounds like you want to create an XML file with three sequential independent roots, corresponding to `Identifier`, `id2` and `id3`.  Such a file would violate the standard, and so `XmlSerializer` does not provide a method to create such a file.

Instead, you should create a container type to hold your other types, and serialize that:

```
Public Class IdContainer
    Public Property Identifier() As Identifier

    Public Property id2() As id2

    Public Property id3() As id3
End Class
```

(There might even be such a class already auto-generated for you by `xsd.exe`.  Check the types generated for any using all three identifier types.)

Sample [fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/FZALSk).